# Bash script is breaking after Continue statement

Tags: bash, scripting

Here I'm trying to ssh to multiple servers remotely and check whether any processes running on those servers and wait until the process to get finished.

```
while read ip name
do
  process=alive
  while [[ "$process" == "alive" ]]
  do
    process=dead
    (if [ 1 -eq "$(echo "$(ssh ubuntu@$ip "top -b -n2 -d 0.5|grep Cpu|awk '{print \$2+\$4}'|tail -n1") > 1" | bc)" ];then
      echo "Process is running on $ip"
      process=alive
      sleep 10
      continue 
    else
      echo "Process is not running on $ip"
      echo "I run some other commands here"
    fi) &
  done
done < ips
wait `jobs -p`
```

The code is breaking after 'continue' statement.

Here is the output

```
+ read ip name
+ process=alive
+ [[ alive == \a\l\i\v\e ]]
+ process=dead
+ [[ dead == \a\l\i\v\e ]]
+ read ip name
+ process=alive
+ [[ alive == \a\l\i\v\e ]]
+ process=dead
+ [[ dead == \a\l\i\v\e ]]
+ read ip name
++ jobs -p
++ bc
+ wait 31090 31091
+++ ssh ubuntu@249.X.X.X 'top -b -n2 -d 0.5|grep Cpu|awk '\''{print $2+$4}'\''|tail -n1'
++ bc
+++ ssh ubuntu@256.X.X.X 'top -b -n2 -d 0.5|grep Cpu|awk '\''{print $2+$4}'\''|tail -n1'
++ echo '20.7 > 1'
+ '[' 1 -eq 1 ']'
+ echo 'Process is running on 249.X.X.X'
Process is running on 249.X.X.X
+ process=alive
+ sleep 10
++ echo '14.6 > 1'
+ '[' 1 -eq 1 ']'
+ echo 'Process is running on 256.X.X.X'
Process is running on 256.X.X.X
+ process=alive
+ sleep 10
+ continue
+ continue
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `ssh` with `ssh -n` to stop reading from stdin (file ips).

---

See: `man ssh`

Answer (score 1):

Using `ssh -n` to redirect `/dev/null` into the standard input of `ssh` should solve the immediate issue though. Without `-n`, `ssh` will read from the `ips` file. But there are other unnecessary things that you do in your code.

Corrected code:

```sh
while read ip name; do
    (
    while true; do
        if ssh -n "ubuntu@$ip" top -b -n2 -d 0.5 | awk '/Cpu/ && n++ { exit($2+$4 > 1) }'
            printf 'Process is running on %s\n' "$ip"
            sleep 10
        else
            printf 'Process is not running on %s\n' "$ip"
            echo 'I run some other commands here'
            break
       fi
    done
    ) &
done <ips

wait
```

I've simplified your code a bit by

- not trying to run more than `top` on the remote host,
- using the exit value of `awk` directly with `if`,
- using `break` to break out of the (now) infinite loop,
- running that loop in the background job, not only the `if` statement, and
- using `wait` without any arguments to wait for all background processes.

Another variant that eliminates the need for the `if` statement all-together:

```sh
while read ip name; do
    (
    while ssh -n "ubuntu@$ip" top -b -n2 -d 0.5 | awk '/Cpu/ && n++ { exit($2+$4 > 1) }'
    do
        printf 'Process is running on %s\n' "$ip"
        sleep 10
    done
    printf 'Process is not running on %s\n' "$ip"
    echo 'I run some other commands here'
    ) &
done <ips

wait
```